# How to install iperf2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, iperf

How to install iperf2 tool in Ubuntu 18.04.1? without Internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it by downloading all required `*.deb` files listed in [its website](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php#ubuntu):

[image: iperf ubuntu deb files]

Choose the version you want and download it with its dependencies. After you have downloaded all those files, you can install them without requiring any Internet connection by using:

```
sudo dpkg -i libsctp1_1.0.18+dfsg-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libiperf0_3.9-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i iperf3_3.9-1_amd64.deb
```

This example shows how to install IPerf 3.9 for Ubuntu 64-bits.

Comment: I installed iperf using sudo apt install iperf

Comment: @hongmeix You asked "without internet connection". Apt requires internet connection...

Comment: In your question you said that you did not have Internet connection.

Comment: Oh, yes, indeed, without internet connection, your method is workable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know that, you're welcome! =)